# gives values to custom data type attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have models in MVC 5

```
public class AppUser
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumbers CellNo { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumbers WorkNo { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumbers HomeNo { get; set; }
    public Address OfficeAddress { get; set; }
}


public class PhoneNumbers
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

}
```

when i want to add data in the model AppUser like

```
 AppUser.WorkNo.CountryCode= array[1];
```

it gives error

```
 "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebApp.dll but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

i think i am doing it wrong please some one guide me to solve this error?
thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference this:

```
AppUser.WorkNo.CountryCode
```

The `WorkNo` property is `null`.  If there was a valid instance of `WorkNo`, you could reference `CountryCode` on that instance.  But since `WorkNo` is a reference type it defaults to `null` unless you instantiate it.

Which you can do in your model's constructor:

```
public class AppUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumbers CellNo { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumbers WorkNo { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumbers HomeNo { get; set; }
    public Address OfficeAddress { get; set; }

    public AppUser()
    {
        CellNo = new PhoneNumbers();
        WorkNo = new PhoneNumbers();
        HomeNo = new PhoneNumbers();
        OfficeAddress = new Address();
    }
}
```

That way the responsibility of maintaining a valid state of the object is encapsulated within the object itself, instantiating its properties to be used by consuming code.